# Paging not working in Ext JS

Tags: extjs, paging

Im a newbie to Ext JS. I just referred to the examples that are posted in Sencha Ext Js and currently am working with Paging in a grid. I'm not sure with how paging works and have a small doubt regarding that. The thing is the paging toolbar is displayed in the bottom of the grid. But all records are displayed in the same page. I tried setting the pageSize inside the store which was suggested in a similar forum and even the autoLoad function, but its not working fine. Here is the sample snippet that I have used in the datastore, grid and the paging toobar.

DataStore code:

```
var itemPageSize = 5;
var bulkDevStore = Ext.create('Ext.data.ArrayStore', {
         pageSize: itemPageSize,
        fields : [ {
            name : 'date'
        }, {
            name : 'userid'
        }, {
            name : 'filename'
        }

        ],

          autoLoad:{ start: 0, limit: itemPageSize} 

    });
```

Grid Snippet:

```
var bulkStatsGrid = Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
        columnLines : true,
        width:'100%',
        height:'100%',
        title : "Statistics",
        store : bulkDevStore,
        disableSelection: true,
        loadMask: true,
        id : 'bulkstatsgrid',

            columns : [ {
            text : 'Date',
            width : '10%',
            sortable : false,
            dataIndex : 'date'
        }, {
            text : 'User Id',
            width : '10%',
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex : 'userid'
        }, {
            text : 'File Name',
            width : '79.8%',
            sortable : true,
            dataIndex : 'filename'
        } ],
```

Paging snippet:

```
            bbar: Ext.create('Ext.PagingToolbar', {
        store: bulkDevStore,
        refresh : false,
        displayInfo: true,
        displayMsg: 'Displaying topics {0} - {1} of {2}',
        emptyMsg: "No topics to display",
```

But always the it shows, Pages 0 of 0 . That entire thing seems disabled. Any help ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got the `total` property:

```
...
total: 'value.total',
pageSize: 5,
...
```

The total property is necessary to be given in your data response for the store.

Try not to `autoload` the store but after creating store and toolbar, call `store.load()`

Answer (score 0):

It is showing Pages 0 of 0 because you didn't provide any data to your datastore,
use data config to provide data.

http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.1.3/#!/api/Ext.data.ArrayStore